# Azure Data Factory - Python Custom Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a data factory using Python Custom Activity (similar to .Net) to extract the data from source files and do some pre-processing on them. After the data is pre-processed, need to upload the file to a blob. I have a python code ready to do this but wanted to explore if i can use Data Factory Custom Activity to do this by injecting Python code into it. If yes, please tell me how to do it, links or any reference docs would help.

Appreciate your thoughts/ideas on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use ADF V2 custom activity for that, here's the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity

Comment: Hi Tong Wu, I dont see any custom activity using Python API. Could you please let me know where it is?

Comment: Custom activity support run cmd command. So you can use command line to invoke python script.

Comment: Hi Tong, I am trying to use Python Application through Custom Activity. May i know how to install dependencies for Python app while using Custom Activity to make calls?

Comment: Hi Nathan, how did you implement it? I have to do it same at my end.

Comment: Same question here , how did you implement this? we have a very similar use case and I know that now you can use Azure Databricks to run Python scripts from ADF V2, but I'm still curious to see how you implemented the custom activity. :) thanks

Comment: Interest also from here!

Comment: Dependencies should be installed at batch pool (referenced by custom activity) level. There are two ways to install dependencies on batch pool: use pool startup scripts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-api-basics#start-tasks-for-compute-nodes or custom image https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies should be installed at batch pool (referenced by custom activity) level. There are two ways to install dependencies on batch pool: use pool startup scripts learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/… or custom image learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images